# Powershell script to use input from .txt or .csv to find a value in a 2nd .csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

Group,
First time posting a question so please be patient. Attempting to use Powershell to read 1 .csv file and search a second .csv for specific data associated with what I passed from the first .csv file. Lets say that both files contain a column with a heading of 'name' with a list of PC names in that column. The 2nd CSV file in addition has a column with a heading named 'id' and that contains a unique ID associated with that PC name (and to complicate matters there may be duplicate PC Names but each one has a unique ID).  I want to work through all the PC names in the first .csv file searching for the corresponding unique id of that PC name in the second .csv file and then set that as a variable so that I can perform some action against it. The code below is what I have so far, I'm manually providing the PC name as I cannot seem to get-content of the first file and pass it to the 2nd file. It will get the unique ID but I cannot seem to get it into a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$computer = "T4763110"
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Devices.csv"
$csv | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $computer } | % id
```

1st CSV file
[First CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axQdr.jpg)

2nd CSV file
[Second CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0n5o.jpg)

Comment: please, do NOT post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify a >`Delimiter`< in your `import-csv`. You can look your delimiter up, when you open your .csv file with the basic Microsoft-Editor.
Mine looks like this:

```
ID;Name
1;Alienware
2;Lexware
3;One
4;Chip
5;Stack
6;Linux
```

I made a new table named dev.csv for myself with following content:

[image]

When executing this code:

```
> $csv = Import-Csv "C:/Users/Desktop/dev.csv" -Delimiter ';'
> $csv
```

Output:

```
ID Name
-- ----
1  Alienware
2  Lexware
3  One
4  Chip
5  Stack
6  Linux
```

Then execute this:

```
 > $csv | where-object {$_.name -eq "Alienware"} | % id
    1
```

To save it to a variable, simply put brackets around it.

```
 > $idvar = ($csv | where-object {$_.name -eq "Alienware"} | % id)
 > $idvar
   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and sorry for not clarifying the delimiter piece of it. My script example currently provides a similar result as yours however what I was asking, though probably not very clearly, is how can I place that output (in your example the '1') into a variable with which I can then perform additional actions on?

Comment: `> $idvar =($csv | where-object {$_.name -eq "Alienware"} | % id)       > $idvar `
Output: 1

Comment: Thank you! You make it look easy. Most of my scripting has been with VB Script and I'm still working my way through some of the nuances of Powershell. I sometimes think it would be easier if I didn't have any VB Script knowledge to get in the way. One of the things that I struggle with is how (or when) to use the brackets, parenthesis curly brackets '{' and what effect they have on the script flow or logic. I marked the question as answered and thanks again.